# How to get random textstring from array, "loop-animation" like lottery?

Tags: java, android

I'm building a very simple Android-app without almost any knowledge in java programming.
The application is almost done and what the app does is that when I press a button it shows a value randomly from an string array.

What I would like to achieve is a small "animation" where it quickly scrolls through all the values ​​in the array and then randomly stops. Almost as a "spinning wheel of text".

I have figuered out that maybe a Timer-function is the way to go. Would be great if someone could help me out.

This is the array with all values:

```
final String[] myNames = {
                "Sax12345",
                "Tyg12345",
                "Djur12345",
                "Hund12345",
                "Trafik2019",
                "Gruvan2019",
                "Kaffe2019"
        };
```

And this is what happens when the button is pressed:

```
        genButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Random randGen = new Random();
                int rando = randGen.nextInt(7);

                textOne.setText(myNames[rando]);
            }
        });
```

Comment: *"maybe a Timer-function is the way to go"* So try it. What is stopping you from searching the web to learn about timers and trying it out for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Simply duplicate (or even multiplicate - depends on the animation length) values inside your array and `shuffle` this. Then in a loop, iterate over the table, putting with some interval the following values to the view, and stop on the last element - this one will be the random one (thanks to the `shuffle` method)

Something like

```
    List<String> presentationList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < HOW_MUCH_SHOULD_IT_BE_MULTIPLICATED; i++) {
        presentationList.addAll(Arrays.asList(myNames));
    }

    Collections.shuffle(presentationList);

    String winnerString = presentationList.get(presentationList.size() - 1); //this is basically winner string

    // now the time for 'animation'
    for(String value : presentationList) {
        textOne.setText(value);
        // wait for a Xms
    }
```